# plugin exited before we could connect

Tags: plugins

i'm new to terraform, Can anyone help me understand why i'm getting the following error after
running terraform plan :
terraform plan:

```
Error: Error asking for user input: 3 error(s) occurred: 

provider.aws: plugin exited before we could connect
provider.templat: plugin exited before we could connect
provider.local : plugin exited before we could connect
i'm using  Terraform v0.11.1
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you C&P the script that generated this error?

Comment: hi Andy thanks for your response, it is not possible to paste terraform scripts, we have multiple scripts for cluster and all those are automated and we are facing the issues with terraform plan and destroy also.